# In AWS API Gateway JWT authorizer, when does AWS fetch the public key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway

In AWS ApiGateway (HTTP), it is possible to setup a JWT Authorizer.
By doing so, we have to provide an issuer URL.
From my understanding, this URL will be used to fetch the public key to verify the signature of the tokens that will be passed.

My question is:

when exactly will apigateway send a request to download the public key ?